# How to split a Crystal Reports subreport across a page break?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, crystal-reports, subreport

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and writing in VB.NET.

I have a subreport in a Crystal Reports report consisting of a list of log entries.  Sometimes the list of log entries is long enough that it would extend onto the next page.  What I see happening is that the list appears on the next page, leaving a big blank space at the bottom of the first page.

I've tried unchecking the "Keep Together" boxes in the "Experts" in a number of different places (sections, groups, etc.) but see no change in the output.

I'm guessing that this isn't the right way to go, but do you know what is?

(I'll be glad to provide more information if I haven't given enough.)

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the subreport's 'keep object together' option.

Comment: Thank you.  I have to deal with Crystal Reports and this was driving me nuts.